# Anime with dragon riders who were the guardians of the North, South, East, West

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember that back in like 2005 there was an anime in a TV station in my country (Mexico) about some dudes that rode Dragons and were like guardians of something (they had cardinal directions, so there was like the guardian of the north, east, south and west).

They had their fights and stuff and I remember that:

- one of the characters (I think it was a secondary character that was royalty or something) had a feline pet that was overpowered and wrecked the protagonists at some point
- one of the bad guys was kind of like a jester and used a needle sword or something
- one of the guardians rode a flying turtle instead of a dragon
- I think it ends with some dudes reading the story of the main characters in a circle (but I may we wrong on that)

I saw it in Spanish.

Comment: I think it ends with some dudes reading the story of the main characters in a circle but I may we wrong on that.

Comment: I also think one of the bad guys was kind of like a jester and used a needle sword or something

Comment: Did the four guardians have any distinctive characteristic? What do you mean with _"feline pet that was op"_? Overpowered? (you could have a look at ["How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/40711) for a list of useful questions to squeeze other details from your memory)

Comment: i dont really remember about the guardians because I didnt get to see all of them. I think one of them rode a flying turtle instead of a dragon though.

Comment: If one of the four guardians rides a dragon and another rides a turtle, then their mounts are likely based on these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Symbols_(China) which may help identify it, though there is a lot of Japanese pop culture that uses that motif.

Comment: @recognizer that does ring a bell

Comment: possibly this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sohryuden:_Legend_of_the_Dragon_Kings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be talking about the *[BT'X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%27t_X)* anime.

> *B't X* is set on an alternate Earth, where a faction known as the Machine Empire rules a significant large piece of land known as "The Area" in the Gobi Desert. The Machine Empire invests highly in scientific advancements and schools children from an early age to become striving scientists. Mechanical engineering have culminated in the creation of cyborgs and most recently mechanical beasts, powered by human blood, the Bt. The series mostly takes place in the Machine Empire, but also on Kamui island, where the main characters were born. An island that was created from a crashed meteor and contains a piece of a sun, far underground.
>
> A B't (pronounced "beat") is the ultimate form of mecha designed for fighting - the B stands for Brain, Blood, Bravery and Battler. They have different forms and powers, usually based on mythological creatures. The B't's source of power is a device called BreakHeart, which is fueled by human blood. Once the BreakHeart is inserted into the B't's body, it creates a link between the blood donor and the B't. A B't is also outfitted with the Guard System, which protects its donor from various dangers and environment changes, such as volcanic heat, the crushing pressures beneath the ocean, or even the depths of space. However, the donor must be in physical contact with his or her B't for the system to work for them. Teppei is able to manifest a suit of protective armor called Battle Gear through use of the Messiah Fist. This has the additional benefit of activating the usually dormant wings on X's sides, enabling him to reach even greater degrees of speed and mobility.

Was kind of popular here in Argentina as well.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Why do you think this is the correct answer? A more thorough answer would be better received.